# WCF Service running in ServiceHost (Console App)

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint, servicehost

I am attempting to wrap a WCF service that was previously running in an .asmx service in the taskbar into a Console App.

Here is the code for wrapping up the WCF Service:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");

        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CheckoutService), uri))
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Prepping CheckoutService server");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                host.Open();

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("CheckoutService server up and running");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Return to stop service at any point");
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();
        }
    }
```

However, the client application that should receive this service (which used to work before the service was wrapped into a console app) is now crashing out with the error:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5000/CheckoutService.svc that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The endpoint configuration for this client in app.config is:

```
<endpoint 
    address="http://localhost:5000/CheckoutService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICheckoutService"
    contract="CheckoutServiceServer.ICheckoutService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICheckoutService" />
```

I think perhaps I am missing some form of `.config` file in the console project hosting the WCF service but i could be wrong!

Comment: Hate to be Captain Obvious but it sounds like the service isn't running.

Comment: You're opening the host, clearing the console, and then you're closing the host again right away.... how is the service supposed to be up and running if you close the host again right away??

Comment: Yeah, i missed the Console.ReadLine() that was meant to keep it open, however after adding that, i'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: If you open this address in web browser http://localhost:5000/CheckoutService.svc?wsdl do you see service description?

Comment: No, there is nothing there.. So the service is not running?

Comment: Looks like it. I see you're using this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx. Check section To test the service.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're closing the host without waiting for user input. Are you missing `Console.ReadLine()`?

Comment: I've added the line now well spotted, however i'm getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have not configured an endpoint for your `ServiceHost` instance. The configuration file you referenced isn't being used, but based on this file you need to configure your `ServiceHost` instance to use the [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) binding and your `CheckoutServiceServer.ICheckoutService` contract to configure your service endpoint via the `ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint()` method.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935.aspx) article for help with hosting a WCF service.